# How to keep high frequency information of audio when upsamling wav from 6khz to 16khz?

Tags: pcm, resampling, spectrogram

When I upsampled wav file(in PCM format) from 6khz to 16khz, and got the spectogram(shown in my google drive link [spectrogram_img](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A1kFjDh3JTgaj2vjCWrS1_iOnKItuXmH/view?usp=sharing)), I found that the high frequency part of the spectrogram was lost.

I have tried using sox and spicy.signal.resample to upsample, but both of them stucked in the same problem mentioned above.

wavsignal = signal.resample(w, (int)(len(w) / 6 * 16))

So why does it happen and how to keep the high frequency information when upsampling?